# GoogleTest EXPECT_CALL throws uninteresting call warning and returns 0 calls

Tags: c++, googletest

I am trying to Mock an external library and test what APIs of the library are being called from my interfaces and I have come across a behavior (first time using mocking) that I can't seem to understand. So, I have a mock class like this:

```cpp
class VulkanLibMock {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(VkResult, vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout, (VkDevice, const VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo *, const VkAllocationCallbacks *, VkDescriptorSetLayout *pSetLayout));
    
    MOCK_METHOD(VkResult, vkCreateDescriptorPool, (VkDevice, const VkDescriptorPoolCreateInfo *, const VkAllocationCallbacks *, VkDescriptorPool *));
};
```

and a test base class to handle values:

```cpp
class VulkanBaseTest : public ::testing::Test {
public:
    VulkanBaseTest() {
        vulkanLibMock = new ::testing::NiceMock<VulkanLibMock>;
    }
    
    ~VulkanBaseTest() {
        delete vulkanLibMock;
        vulkanLibMock = nullptr;
    }
    
public:
    static VulkanLibMock *vulkanLibMock;
};
```

So, I inherited a test class from it:

```cpp
class VulkanDescriptorManagerTests : public VulkanBaseTest {
public:
    VulkanDescriptorManagerTests() = default;
};
```

and added one test case:

```
TEST_F(VulkanDescriptorManagerTests, MyTest) {

ON_CALL(*vulkanLibMock, vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout).WillByDefault([](VkDevice, const VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo *, const VkAllocationCallbacks *, VkDescriptorSetLayout *) {
  std::cout << "Called: vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout";
  return VK_SUCCESS;
});
    
ON_CALL(*vulkanLibMock, vkCreateDescriptorPool).WillByDefault([](VkDevice, const VkDescriptorPoolCreateInfo *, const VkAllocationCallbacks *, VkDescriptorPool *) {
  std::cout << "Called: vkCreateDescriptorPool";
  return VK_SUCCESS;
});
    
// this is the class that I am trying to test
VulkanDescriptorManager manager(nullptr);    
EXPECT_CALL(*vulkanLibMock, vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout);

}
```

If I don't use `NiceMock`, I get the following warning when running tests

```
Called: vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout <-- cout in `ON_CALL`
Uninteresting mock function call - taking default action specified at:
VulkanDescriptorManager.test.cpp:12:
    Function call: vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(NULL, 0x7ffeefbfec50, NULL, 0x7ffeefbfedf0)
          Returns: 0
NOTE: You can safely ignore the above warning unless this call should not happen.  Do not suppress it by blindly adding an EXPECT_CALL() if you don't mean to enforce the call.  See https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#knowing-when-to-expect for details.
Called: vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout <-- cout in `ON_CALL`
GMOCK WARNING:
Uninteresting mock function call - taking default action specified at:
VulkanDescriptorManager.test.cpp:12:
    Function call: vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(NULL, 0x7ffeefbfec20, NULL, 0x7ffeefbfedf8)
          Returns: 0
NOTE: You can safely ignore the above warning unless this call should not happen.  Do not suppress it by blindly adding an EXPECT_CALL() if you don't mean to enforce the call.  See https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#knowing-when-to-expect for details.
Called: vkCreateDescriptorPool <-- cout in `ON_CALL`
GMOCK WARNING:
Uninteresting mock function call - taking default action specified at:
VulkanDescriptorManager.test.cpp:17:
    Function call: vkCreateDescriptorPool(NULL, 0x7ffeefbfeca0, NULL, 0x7ffeefbfee00)
          Returns: 0
NOTE: You can safely ignore the above warning unless this call should not happen.  Do not suppress it by blindly adding an EXPECT_CALL() if you don't mean to enforce the call.  See https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#knowing-when-to-expect for details.
```

And, I get an error regardless of using NiceMock:

```
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(*vulkanLibMock, vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout)...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
```

What am I missing here? I know that the function is called since can see the output of `cout` statement in `ON_CALL` implementation. Why does `EXPECT_CALL` thinks that the function is not called?

**EDIT:** VulkanDescriptorManager (simplified):

```cpp
VulkanDescriptorManager(VkDevice device) {
  // global library functions
  VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo sceneCreateInfo{};
  vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(device, &createInfo, nullptr, &this->sceneDescriptorSet);

  VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo materailCreateInfo{};
  vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(device, &materailCreateInfo, nullptr, &this->materialDescriptorSet);

  // same logic for vkCreateDescriptorPool
}
```

The called functions are global and were coming from library. In order to be able to test them, I unlinked the library and created my own implementation for the functions:

```cpp
// this is in my global library mock file:

VkResult vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(
    VkDevice device, const VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo *pCreateInfo,
    const VkAllocationCallbacks *pAllocator,
                                     VkDescriptorSetLayout *pSetLayout) {
    // Calls the function in mock that is accessible from
    // VulkanBaseTest's static variable
    return VulkanBaseTest::vulkanLibMock->vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(device, pCreateInfo, pAllocator, pSetLayout);
}


VkResult vkCreateDescriptorPool(VkDevice device,
                                  const VkDescriptorPoolCreateInfo *pCreateInfo,
                                  const VkAllocationCallbacks *pAllocator,
                       VkDescriptorPool *pDescriptorPool) {
    return VulkanTestFixture::vulkanLibMock->vkCreateDescriptorPool(device, pCreateInfo, pAllocator, pDescriptorPool);
}
```

Comment: What is VulkanDescriptorManager and how does it involve vulkanLibMock?

Comment: `EXPECT_CALL(*vulkanLibMock, vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout);` does this compile without expected parameters or placeholders?

Comment: Seems we need to adjust these two statements sequence: `VulkanDescriptorManager manager(nullptr);    
EXPECT_CALL(*vulkanLibMock, vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout);`

Comment: I updated my post with a simplified version of VulkanDescriptorSet (basically put all the logic from internal private functions to constructor).

Comment: Regarding EXPECT_CALL, there were no errors but I also added one with placeholders: `EXPECT_CALL(*vulkanLibMock, vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(_, _, _, _));` but tests still fail.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin Why do I need to change the order if `VulkanDescriptorManager` calls these functions first.

Comment: Where is your full test? Generally, we need to put `EXPECT_CALL` before the actual body of our test.

Comment: The code snippet with on_call, Descriptor Manager and expect call is the full test case.

Comment: Added test function to code snippet as well

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin thank you for the help! I was setting expect call after calling test body. I had to do it before the body as you mentioned. I wish this this mock functionality was more intuitive and sequential like EXPECT_EQ etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the gmock [doc](http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_for_dummies.html)

> Important note: gMock requires expectations to be set before the mock
> functions are called, otherwise the behavior is undefined. Do not
> alternate between calls to EXPECT_CALL() and calls to the mock
> functions, and do not set any expectations on a mock after passing the
> mock to an API.

Your code need to adjust these two lines sequence from:

```cpp
VulkanDescriptorManager manager(nullptr);    
EXPECT_CALL(*vulkanLibMock, vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout);
```

to:

```cpp
EXPECT_CALL(*vulkanLibMock, vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout);
VulkanDescriptorManager manager(nullptr);
```

The doc has also explained why they use such design:

> Why does gMock work like that? Well, specifying the expectation
> beforehand allows gMock to report a violation as soon as it rises,
> when the context (stack trace, etc) is still available. This makes
> debugging much easier.